# WinForms : vScrollBar for ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scrollbar

I want to bind a vScrollBar control to my listview because the default verticalScrollBar of my listview can't be wider. I don't know how to process to bind this two control and can scroll my listview with this vScrollBar. If someone has experimented the same things and have advice for me he is welcome.

What I'm trying to do is catch scroll event on vScrollBar to affect the position of my listview's scrollbar but it's not working :

```
private void VScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{            
     Point a = new Point(0, vScrollBar1.Value);
     listNotif.AutoScrollOffset = a;            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to scroll `ListView` with custom `vScrollBar`:

```
private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    listNotif.EnsureVisible(e.NewValue);
}
```

Comment: listNotif is a listview not a listbox.
listNotif.TabIndex doesn't work and listview doesn't have TopIndex propertie

Comment: @MrB3NiT0 Looks like for the `ListView` only thing you can do is to call `EnsureVisible`. I edited my post.

Comment: Nice my vScrollBar now affect the scroll on my listview, i will perform some test to have a complete synchronisation of the two scrollbar to complete your answer. Have you any idea how can the two scrollbar have the same vertical height scroll?

Comment: @MrB3NiT0 You can use `listNotif.LargeChange` property to control the height of the scroll.

Comment: thanks a lot just to complete when I set my listview I set : 
 `vScrollBar.Value = 0;`  to go at the top of my listview,
`vScrollBar.Maximum = listNotif.Items.Count - 1 + vScrollBar.LargeChange -1;` to be sure the bottom of scroll is the same for the original scroll and my vScrollBar